# Is it Dio create new isolate for each request in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, parallel-processing, dio

When create single instance of Dio and call multiple requests from this instance , is't Dio create new isolate in each request or same isolate will be reused , and if I create multi Dio instances and make call request from each one , is't will create isolates for each request on this case?

I am trying to know if there is any benefits from sending multiple request in same time simultaneously.

Comment: i don't think that `dio` uses any `Isolate` at all - the same applies to standard `http` package

Comment: @pskink, I think `dio` will do the deserialization of JSON in background isolate if possible, when JSON size is >= 50 kb, check the [BackgroundTransformer](https://github.com/cfug/dio/blob/adc6842d6664d427bb06bc44aa870340bd127ef4/dio/lib/src/transformers/background_transformer.dart#L10).

Comment: @VladimirGadzhov indeed, but it's an add-on, not used by default (it is used only for JSON response parsing)